# How can I check that '0,1,2' exists in a.keys() and if does not exist then add '0,1,2'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am having some trouble confronting this problem.

```
a = {
    None: {0: None, 1: None},
    '1,2': {0: '0,1,2', 1: None}
}
```

I would like to verify that a's values which are dictionaries have a value which exists in `a.keys()`, if it does not exist then add it as a key with a `dict()` value.

In this case, `None` values exist in `a.keys()` but `'0,1,2'`does not so I just add it to `a.keys()` and would have something like this.

```
a = {
    None: {0: None, 1: None},
    '1,2': {0: '0,1,2', 1: None},
    '0,1,2': {}
}
```

After some other operations, the empty dictionary will have some keys and values.

For example,

```
a = {
    None: {0: None, 1: None},
    '1,2': {0: '0,1,2', 1: None},
    '0,1,2': {0: None, 1: '0,1'}
}
```

Now `'0,1'` does not exist in `a.keys()` so I will add it.

So I need to verify over and over again that `a.values()` which are dictionaries, have their values in `a.keys()`.

Comment: You guys use some really weird data structures

Comment: So you need to write an `if` block... what's unusual about that?

Comment: Question isn't fully clear. Provide some more examples.

Comment: '1,2' in a.keys() Would this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of all missing values by iterating through all values of your "value dictionaries" by checking if they are not present as a key in the original dictionary

```
def add_keys(d):
    missing_values = [v for vdict in d.values() for v in vdict.values() if v not in d]
    for k in missing_values:
        d[k] = {}
```

Note that generating `missing_values` takes time proportional to the total number of values present in all the "value dictionaries" of `d`:

So now if you call `add_keys` on `a` any time, it should update `a` with the missing keys:

```
a = {None: {0: None, 1: None},
    '1,2': {0: '0,1,2', 1: None}}

add_keys(a)
print(a)
# {'1,2': {0: '0,1,2', 1: None}, '0,1,2': {}, None: {0: None, 1: None}}

a = {None: {0: None, 1: None},
    '1,2': {0: '0,1,2', 1: None},
    '0,1,2': {0: None, 1: '0,1'}}

add_keys(a)
print(a)
# {'1,2': {0: '0,1,2', 1: None}, '0,1': {}, '0,1,2': {0: None, 1: '0,1'}, None: {0: None, 1: None}}
```